# Geth pending transactions are not broadcasting too network even with high gasPrice

Tags: ethereum, geth

Due to the network congestion in ethereum network my node has 100s of pending ethereum transactions. Is there any way we can make these transactions invalid or resend using Higher transaction fees in one go?

Comment: I also need a solution to this.